# Fullscreen in Safari for iPad, iPhone

Tags: javascript

What would be the code for `fullScreen` and `cancelFullScreen` in Safari, following this code?:

```
var docEl = document.documentElement;

if      (docEl.requestFullScreen)       docEl.requestFullScreen();
else if (docEl.msRequestFullscreen)     docEl.msRequestFullscreen();
else if (docEl.mozRequestFullScreen)    docEl.mozRequestFullScreen();
else if (docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen) docEl.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

Comment: Doesn't Safari use WebKit? Check this link out, it is very helpful and may solve your issue: [*HTML5 Rocks!: Building an amazing fullscreen mobile experience*](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/) :)

Answer (score -1):

Change your body id to 'body'and Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var is_safari = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") > -1;
      var elem = document.getElementById("body");

if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
 (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
  if (is_safari){

    elem.onclick = function() {
        req = elem.requestFullScreen || elem.webkitRequestFullScreen || elem.mozRequestFullScreen;
        req.call(elem);
    }
    }
 }
 $(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
 elem.webkitExitFullScreen();
    }
});
 </script>
```

Comment: This solution does not work as iOS Safari (currently 9.2) [does not support fullscreen API at all](http://caniuse.com/#search=fullscreen).

Comment: @oleq, although it's true that `elem.webkitRequestFullscreen()` doesn't seem to work, your statement may be interpreted too broadly. I've been able to get iPad video to go fullscreen with `video.webkitEnterFullscreen()`.